# PowerShell for loop pattern check

Tags: git, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I wanted to search for missing Id from PowerShell for loop

I'm using this command

> git log  -10 --no-merges master  | Select-String -Pattern "commit"

then doing for loop

> ```
> foreach($commit in $commitMessage) {
>         Write-Host $commit.
>     }
> ```

If one pre-commit Id missing I need to exit the loop (need to skip the loop if pre commit not existing)

example: if Highlighted Id missing How can find that? can we check patterns?

loop retuning list like this

1 Commit id
2 Pre-commit
3 Commit  id
4 Pre-commit
etc...

[image]

Comment: You want to "exit" the loop after running through all the messages, or do you want to _skip_ the loop completely if the given precommit hash is not there?

Comment: Thanks yes need to skip the loop if pre commit  not existing

Comment: `git log --grep Precommit-verified` shows you only commits whose log messages contain that string.

Answer (score 1):

The following **assumes that you're looking for the presence of commit lines that aren't followed by at least one precommit line** rather than looking for a specific precommit hash.

```
$havePreCommit = $true; $missing = $false
$commitAndPreCommitLines = 
  switch -Regex (git log -10 --no-merges master) {
    '^commit ' {
      if (-not $havePreCommit) { $missing = $true; break }
      $havePreCommit = $false
      $_ # output
      continue
    }
    '^\s+Precommit-Verified:' {
      $havePreCommit = $true
      $_ # output
    }
  }
$missing = $missing -or -not $havePreCommit

if ($missing) {
  Write-Warning "Not all commit lines are followed by at least one precommit line."
} else {
  # Output the collected lines (no need for a loop).
  $commitAndPreCommitLines
}
```

The solution uses a [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Switch) statement with [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) matching.
This allows you to maintain state across lines, which [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) alone cannot do.

Comment: As I understand it powershell lifted a trick from cms pipes and runs its filters as (roughly) coroutines using i/o as call and yield, so this is not so horrifying as it might seem. I'd argue it's an open question whether it's harder to understand what this is trying to achieve than the `sed`.

Comment: @jthill, unless parallelism is explicitly requested, PowerShell's processing is single-threaded, as far as I know. Communication with external programs (child processes) happens via pipes, while PowerShell-native commands (so-called cmdlets) are instances of (in-process) .NET classes that are coordinated via method calls in a PowerShell pipeline. While output is generally streaming, it situationally requires collecting up front, namely with language statements such as `switch` and `foreach`. To make the above streaming, `git ... | ForEach-Object { ... }` would have to be used, which is slower.

Comment: @jthill, as for readability: Speaking as someone who used to answer `sed` questions a few years back: I've always found the more advanced `sed` features mind-bending, and whatever grasp of them I used to has evaporated with non-use. PowerShell is undoubtedly more verbose, but its naming conventions (which even cover methodical naming of short aliases) and rich language support to me make it easier to write maintainable scripts. That said, when performance matters, there's no substitute for (compiled) external tools.

Comment: Yah, was it you helped me beat that line-gaggle idiom in to shape? I owe you a debt of gratitude for that, it turns many tasks into casual oneliners like the one in my answer here. I'd found a cruder rendition on my own but I can't have been the first..

Comment: Thanks, @jthill, I don't remember, but even if it was me, I doubt I came up with it on my own.

Answer (score 0):

`git log --grep Precommit-Verified` will show you only commits whose messages contain that string, but when you're postprocessing you'll be searching for that string anyway so maybe it's best to not duplicate the searches.

There's an easy oneliner for this with unix tools,

```
git rev-list -10 --no-merges --pretty='%w(0,4,4)%B' master \
| sed '/^commit/!{/Precommit-Verified:/H;$!d};x;/\n/!d'
```

is probably better for this task, it just drops any group that didn't find the body line you're looking for.

`/firstline/!{...H;$!d};x` is a group-accumulation idiom; the first line of each group gets `x`changed into the hold buffer, and the accumulated lines from the previous group are processed as a unit. Here we're just picking the Precommit-Verified lines, and only printing groups that have more than just the header.

I'd be interested in a powershell way to do this too, it really doesn't seem suited for tasks down in oneliner territory like this.

Comment: Getting this  message "sed: The term 'sed' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again."

Comment: Yah, those are unix tools, I don't know how to do it with powershell, sorry.

Comment: There's nothing as terse as `sed`, but PowerShell's `switch` statement has Awk-like capabilities; please see my answer.